# VBA: How to Make and Rename a Slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need help on a sample scenario:

I have a slide and have a command button on it. When clicked, it should pop up a window/ image and when clicked again should dispose the window. We can do it. When copied into another deck, I cannot use the default slide name from deck 1. how can I make a slide with VBA code behind work in any deck without any modifications? Also, how do I rename a slide in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Powerpoint are you using?  I'm not sure how your command button can be tied to the name of the deck.  Copying the slide should update the code automatically.

If you're having trouble copying the slide to a new presentation, you could try using a template, or a PowerPoint add-in that allows you to insert the button and code in one action.